# drawn thumbnails in tlistbox

Tags: image, delphi, listbox, thumbnails

In DelphiXE, I'm using a tFileOpenDialog to select a folder and then listing all the *.jpg files in that folder in a tListBox.  I'm allowing the list items to be dragged and dropped within the list for custom sorting so that I can display them in order later.

I'd like to be able to draw a thumbnail of the image beside the filename so that the display is similar to Windows Explorer when looking at files in List view where you have the associated icon just left of the file name on the same row.

I've found a couple of old examples that lead me to believe this is possible using tListBox.onDrawItem, but I've been unable to get one to work.

What is the best approach to take to accomplish this goal using a tListBox, or by some other means?

Thanks for your help.

---

Update:  I've been working to use tListView instead, as suggested.

I've attempted to convert the examples from Ken and Andreas to use actual images instead of dynamically created sample bitmaps.  I was able to get the basics working, but without resizing, I get only the top left of the image 64*64.  I'm only working with JPGs at this point.  imagecount is just the count of my list of filenames in my listbox, I haven't moved the initial list creation into the listview at this point.

That is done with this code:

```
procedure TfrmMain.CreateThumbnails;
var
  i: Integer;
  FJpeg: TJpegImage;
  R: TRect;
begin
  for i := 0 to imageCount - 1 do
  begin
    FJpeg := TJpegImage.Create;
    thumbs[i] := TBitmap.Create;
    FJpeg.LoadFromFile(Concat(imgFolderlabel.caption,
      photoList.Items.Strings[i]));
    thumbs[i].Assign(FJpeg);
    thumbs[i].SetSize(64, 64); 
  end;
  imgListView.LargeImages := ImageList1;
  FJpeg.Free;
end;
```

In order to also resize and stretch the image properly within the thumbnail, I'm trying to implement some code from here: http://delphi.about.com/od/graphics/a/resize_image.htm

The new code looks like:

```
procedure TfrmMain.CreateThumbnails;
var
  i: Integer;
  FJpeg: TJpegImage;
  R: TRect;
begin
  for i := 0 to imageCount - 1 do
  begin
      FJpeg := TJpegImage.Create;
      thumbs[i] := TBitmap.Create;
      FJpeg.LoadFromFile(Concat(imgFolderlabel.caption,
        photoList.Items.Strings[i]));
      thumbs[i].Assign(FJpeg);

      //resize code
      R.Left := 0;
      R.Top := 0;
      // proportional resize
      if thumbs[i].Width > thumbs[i].Height then
      begin
        R.Right := 64;
        R.Bottom := (64 * thumbs[i].Height) div thumbs[i].Width;
      end
      else
      begin
        R.Bottom := 64;
        R.Right := (64 * thumbs[i].Width) div thumbs[i].Height;
      end;
      thumbs[i].Canvas.StretchDraw(R, thumbs[i]);
      // resize image
      //thumbs[i].Width := R.Right;
      //thumbs[i].Height := R.Bottom;

      thumbs[i].SetSize(64, 64); //all images must be same size for listview

  end;
  imgListView.LargeImages := ImageList1;
  FJpeg.Free;
end;
```

This gives me a collage of image thumbnails with their filenames and works good.

Thank you.

Comment: OnDrawItem sounds good. Why could you not get it to work?

Comment: @Bobby: Owner-drawn listboxes are difficult to keep in synch if you're allowing them to be rearranged by dragging. Have you considered using a TListView instead? It has built-in support for images, and you can load the thumbnails into an imagelist which gets associated with each item by the imageindex.

Comment: @Bobby, @Ken: Yes, the `TListView` feels like a more natural control to use when listing files. After all, Windows uses this control.

Comment: @David: the samples I found were for more complex implementations and I was having trouble molding it to my needs and was hoping for a more basic approach.

@Ken, @Andreas: Thanks for the sample, and I will also give the ListView a shake and see how that goes and report back.

Thanks!

Comment: @Andreas @Ken: I have updated my question, I hope this is the correct way to ask a followup/clarification

Comment: @Bobby Based on your added info, the problem is that all images in the ImageList need to be the same size. Figure out what the largest size is you'll allow, create each bitmap that size, fill the background with a transparent color (the color the ListView's background is set to), and then draw the thumbnail inside that bitmap.

Comment: @Ken:  Well, that was easy enough to fix.  Thanks for all your help!

Comment: This works fine but is a bit slow when working with larger images, 1 second each for a 3 meg file, but I guess that's to be expected.

Comment: @Bobby: A 3-meg file takes time to load and resize - 1 second doesn't seem too bad. Is there any way you can save the thumbs once they've been generated, so you won't have to generate all of them again the next time the folder is visited?

Comment: @Ken:  Possibly, but in most cases these are only going to be used once.  And even though this would be helpful, the time delay may force me to abandon it.  I'm not sure how Windows handles the thumbnails you see in explorer, but it would be nice if you could just tap into that and get them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not an answer, but an alternative (using Andreas' code for creating the image array as a starting point). Drop a TListView and a TImageList on a new form, cut all the code from the editor from the `interface` to just above the final `end.` with this:

```
uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ImgList, ComCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ImageList1: TImageList;
    ListView1: TListView;
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure CreateListItems;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

const
  N = 50;
  THUMB_WIDTH = 32;
  THUMB_HEIGHT = 32;
  THUMB_PADDING = 4;

var
  thumbs: array[0..N-1] of TBitmap;

procedure CreateThumbnails;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to N - 1 do
  begin
    thumbs[i] := TBitmap.Create;
    thumbs[i].SetSize(THUMB_WIDTH, THUMB_HEIGHT);
    thumbs[i].Canvas.Brush.Color := RGB(Random(255), Random(255), Random(255));
    thumbs[i].Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0, 0, THUMB_WIDTH, THUMB_HEIGHT));
  end;
end;


procedure TForm1.CreateListItems;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to N - 1 do
  begin
    with ListView1.Items.Add do
    begin
      Caption := 'Item ' + IntToStr(i);
      ImageIndex := i;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  CreateThumbnails;
  for i := 0 to N - 1 do
    ImageList1.Add(thumbs[i], nil);
  ListView1.LargeImages := ImageList1;
  CreateListItems;
end;
```

[image]

Comment: +1. This I think is a better solution. Feel free to insert http://privat.rejbrand.se/listviewthumbs2.png into your answer.

Comment: @Andreas: Thanks. :) It is an improvement.

Answer (score 1):

`OnDrawItem` is a good way to go.

Simple example:

```
const
  N = 50;
  THUMB_WIDTH = 64;
  THUMB_HEIGHT = 64;
  THUMB_PADDING = 4;

var
  thumbs: array[0..N-1] of TBitmap;

procedure CreateThumbnails;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to N - 1 do
  begin
    thumbs[i] := TBitmap.Create;
    thumbs[i].SetSize(THUMB_WIDTH, THUMB_HEIGHT);
    thumbs[i].Canvas.Brush.Color := RGB(Random(255), Random(255), Random(255));
    thumbs[i].Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0, 0, THUMB_WIDTH, THUMB_HEIGHT));
  end;
end;

procedure TForm4.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  with ListBox1.Items do
  begin
    BeginUpdate;
    for i := 0 to N - 1 do
      Add(Format('This is item %d.', [i]));
    EndUpdate;
  end;
  ListBox1.ItemHeight := 2*THUMB_PADDING + THUMB_HEIGHT;
  CreateThumbnails;
end;

procedure TForm4.ListBox1DrawItem(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer;
  Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
var
  dc: HDC;
  s: string;
  r: TRect;
begin
  dc := TListBox(Control).Canvas.Handle;
  s := TListBox(Control).Items[Index];
  FillRect(dc, Rect, GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH));
  BitBlt(dc,
    Rect.Left + THUMB_PADDING,
    Rect.Top + THUMB_PADDING,
    THUMB_WIDTH,
    THUMB_HEIGHT,
    thumbs[Index].Canvas.Handle,
    0,
    0,
    SRCCOPY);
  r := Rect;
  r.Left := Rect.Left + 2*THUMB_PADDING + THUMB_WIDTH;
  DrawText(dc,
    PChar(s),
    length(s),
    r,
    DT_SINGLELINE or DT_VCENTER or DT_LEFT or DT_END_ELLIPSIS);
end;
```

In a real-world scenario, the `thumbs` array would contain the actual image thumbs. In this example, however, the "thumbnails" consist of single-colour squares.

[image]

Comment: @Ken, thanks, but I too think the OP should consider a `TListView` instead.

Comment: couldn't resist posting the alternative TListView. No pretty picture, though. ;)